# character "^$" in string

Tags: c++, string, char

it may be a naive question, but i don't know what these codes do

```
"^$","^","$"
```

in function

```
 string preProcess(string s) 
  {
    int n = s.length();
    if (n == 0) return "^$";
    string ret = "^";

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    ret += "#" + s.substr(i, 1); 

    ret += "#$";
    return ret;
}
```

The purpose of the function is to insert "#" between every character in string s. For example, change string "aba" to "#a#b#a#". 
I couldn't figure out what "^$" does here. And if I change them, it causes run time error.

Thanks !

Comment: is the returned string being used as a regular expression by chance?

Comment: `And if I change them, it causes run time error.`  What uses the result of this function?  The function itself shouldn't cause a runtime error.

Comment: `s.substr(i, 1);` lol?

Comment: Well, did you look at where the resulting string is used....?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant The returned string T is used by the main function to read char T[i].  The code is from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-palindromic-substring-set-2/ . It's to find the longest palindromic substring in O(n) time.  I don't understand the necessity of ^ and $ here.

Comment: @Mr.Llama please see above comment. Thanks !

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit please see above comment. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

`^` is a start of line marker. `$` is an end of line marker. If the input is empty, this function just returns `^$`, an empty line. Otherwise it returns `"^...$"` where the `...` is interleaved with `#` as you describe.

The `^` and `$` were likely chosen because of their use as start- and end-of-line markers in most varieties of regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The returned string T is used by the main function to read char T[i]. The code is from geeksforgeeks.org/longest-palindromic-substring-set-2 . It's to find the longest palindromic substring in O(n) time. Could you explain the necessity of ^ and $ here?